# After upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 - The type or namespace name 'xxxxxxxxx_ascx' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP'

Tags: c#, asp.net

We recently upgraded our website project to Visual Studio 2010.

I am now getting this error whenever I try to Publish the Website with the "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" checked.

This worked previously using Visual Studio 2008 so I am not sure why it is not working now.

```
The type or namespace name 'xxxxxxxxx_ascx' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' 
(are you     missing an assembly reference?)
```

The lines causing the error are all doing this sort of thing.

```
ASP.content_Controls_Info_ascx infoControl = new ASP.content_Controls_Info_ascx();
infoControl.Stages =  query.ToList();
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(infoControl);
```

I have not upgraded anything else so the dot net framework is still 3.5

The site builds fine and a publish works without "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" checked. The content_Controls_Info_ascx part of the code also highlights the class name so it is finding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **.sln** file find section related to your Web Site Project. It looks like this:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "YourWebProject", "..\WEB\YourWebProject", "{A3774FE1-AA19-4A0F-94C9-FA58084B2429}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        ProjectReferences = "..."
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/YourWebProject"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\WEB\YourWebProject\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\YourWebProject\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/YourWebProject"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\WEB\YourWebProject\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\YourWebProject\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "2487"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

and set following properties to "**false**" (I used Notepad to edit .sln file):

- Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "**false**"
- Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "**false**"

by default they were set to "**true**" and error was occurred:

> The type or namespace name 'xxxxxxxxx_ascx' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' 
>   (are you     missing an assembly reference?)

This solution helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Website templates. The solution to this is to convert to a Web Application project. More info:

http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/01/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Sep/12/Understanding-Page-Inheritance-in-ASPNET-20

You could check your references in case that's what's happening but with the website template you are likely to run into this issue again especially with user controls and external projects/libraries.